# Is there way to query multiple urls using chrome.tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am writing a chrome extension and it needs to work on multiple sites.
Is there away I can modify this tabs.query to detect additional urls other than amazon?

It would be better if there was a way to detect website tags like for shopping or video related websites. Im very new to chrome extension programming.

```
chrome.tabs.query({ url: 'https://www.amazon.com/*', }, (tabs) => {
      alert("site detected");
      tabs.forEach(tab => {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
      });
    });
```

Comment: url is string or string[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass multiple URLs as an array.

```js
chrome.tabs.query({ url: [ /* array of URL patterns */ ]}, tabs => {
    // ...
});
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-query). It states the following for the `url` property of `queryInfo`:

> Match tabs against one or more URL patterns. Fragment identifiers are not matched. This property is ignored if the extension does not have the "tabs" permission.

Answer (score 0):

Just filter them out later. Since you'll be using MV3, you can do it like this:

```js
(await chrome.tabs.query({})).filter(t => 
  ['https://www.amazon.com/', 'https://www.example.com/']
  .some(m => t.url.startsWith(m))
).forEach(t => chrome.tabs.remove(t.id))
```